# The equation to find chance that something will happen in a game

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the chance that an item will drop in the game I'm playing, or a similar event will happen. For a while I thought 
100 - (chance it won't happen)^n * 100, was the corrent equation, where n is the number of times I've killed a monster. Then I realized, when you get, let's say up to 50%, then the chance would be 50%, then 75%, then 87.5, etc. meaning that I messed up.

My question is, what would the proper equation be. I've done some expermenting and found that 100 - (chance it won't happen)^(n^2) * 100 may be the correct equation. is this correrct?

BTW the game is called terraria, but that doesn't really matter with this.

EDIT: to be clear, the chance that the item will drop does not increase every time it's killed, it's always a certain chance that the item is dropped.
I used logic to realize that if you have a certain chance, let's call it a 50% chance that it'll drop, that means every time I kill it, it's 50% chance that it'll drop. However, I can use the idea that the chance of it NOT happening will "decrease" because the chance for it to not happen twice is, 0.5 time 0.5 or .25.

The problem I was noticing, that you would have to worry about the previous values in the graphed equation, so that chance # 100 doesn't just worry about the 1st chance, but also 2 through 99.

Comment: Why do you think your original answer is incorrect?

Comment: I don't think that the original answer is correct, I think the new one may be. Also I wrote the new one, with "the birthday problem" equation in mind

Comment: But why? The original should be correct if I am understanding your question properly.

Comment: "Then I realized, when you get, let's say up to 50%, then the chance would be 50%, then 75%, then 87.5, etc. meaning that I messed up."

Comment: I read your post. Why do you think that trend should not occur?

Comment: I think believe that trend will occure, just not in the equation.
like if you put it on a graph, that trend will not occure. so, the equation that I think / thaught would work, the newer one, appears to be correct when graphed. because in the previous equations graph, the slope would slowly go down, as it approached 100% but with the new one, its slope increase, until it gets to a certain point.

Comment: But *why* do you think the slope of the correct function should increase before it starts decreasing? (By the way, it doesn't even entirely make sense to talk about slope, since you can only have integer $n$.)

Comment: If graphed, both equations have a slope, and it does change, just put the equation into google, and you'll see.

Also it should increase before it decreases, because it should speed up quickly as it reaches, let's say 50% because 50% of 50 is 25, so add them together, now you're at 75 (read the question for why that makes sense), but then it'll slow down at let's say 90% because it's really close to the top possible percent of 100%

Comment: The equations only have slopes because Google assumes that $n$ varies continuously. You cannot kill half a monster ($n=0.5$). It only makes sense to consider the equation defined at the points $n=0,1,2,\dots$. Anyway, I saw that you clarified each monster only has one specific drop rate. That means original equation (which is equivalent to the one in Conrado's answer) was correct.

Comment: Even if you only include integeres, it still has slope.

Comment: Not really. Lines have slope; groups of separated points do not. You can of course still determine the slope of a line connecting one point to the next, but if you do that, you'll find that the lines for your solution involving $n^2$ also have slopes that are strictly decreasing from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at every time you kill a monster an item may appear let's assume it does appear independently of the  previous  number of monsters you killed then the probability is just fixed $p$

the probability that at least an item will appear after n mosters were killed is given by $$1 - (1-p)^n $$

If you assume $p = 50 \%$ then you can compute some numbers

$P(\text{ no item after 10 rounds}) = 1 - (0.5)^{10} = 0.9990234375$

Comment: 1−(1−p1)(1−p2)⋯(1−pn), does that mean, 1−(1−p^1)(1−p^2)⋯(1−p^n) or
1−(1−p*1)(1−p*2)⋯(1−p*n)

Comment: If you use \$\$ your post will be in better format

Comment: $p_i$ is the probability of dropping an item at after $i$ mosters were killed  $(1 - p_i)$  is the probability that no item falls at at "round" i

Comment: that's kind of what I was asking about, (1−$pi$) is that, (1 - p*i) or what?

it helps if you give me some form of "actual" example. like instead of just putting p, put like an actual chance

Comment: do you want concrete numbers?

Comment: As it is a probability one must choose $p_i \in (0,1)$. For instance let $n = 3$ $p_1 = 0.1$ $p_2 = 0.5$ and $p_3 = 0.8$ you will get $1 - (0.9)*(0.5)*(0.2) = 0.91$ this means that  at least an item will have fall with probability $0.91$ after 3 mosters were killed

Comment: that almost makes sense to me, to be clear though,
"p1=0.1 p2=0.5 and p3=0.8" are just random numbers right? because if they are, then that's why this won't work for me. I'm gonna put what I need in this equation in the actual post

sorry for being difficult.

Comment: That's all right. I think your question is more interesting than it appears, since one may start to think about the following. How do I guess the probability distribution that the specific random variable follows. That is an inference problem. A non trivial one. The trivial answer would be: "Ask the guy who made the game how it is calculated".